# Is it not possible to change font family of <body> in Bootstrap 5?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

The Font-Family changes for my heading tags, but my body tag keeps getting canceled out by the "`_reboot.scss:50`". Also when I inspect my webpage and toggle off the default "`enter code here`font-family: var(--bs-body-font-family);" the font I have selected in the CSS works.

Tried Both Import and Link for the Google Font :

```html
<style>
  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@300;900&display=swap');
</style>
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@300;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

Css Selector :

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use !important to override css.
Example -

```
body {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif !important;
}
```

Comment: Don't use important unless you absolutely need it. It introduces problems with specificity. And in this case, you don't need it.

Answer (score 3):

Overriding in CSS with `!important` will work, but it also means that your user's browser may download superfluous fonts.  [Bootstrap has recommended, idiomatic ways to customize your Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/customize/overview/).  For instance, if you are using SASS you can [override variable defaults](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/customize/sass/#variable-defaults) to set your own font as the Bootstrap font, something like:

```css
// Required
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";

// Default variable overrides
$font-family-sans-serif:      'Montserrat', system-ui, -apple-system, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", "Noto Sans", "Liberation Sans", Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji" !default;
// stylelint-enable value-keyword-case

// Required
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/root";

// Optional Bootstrap components here
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/reboot";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/type";
// etc
```

I would recommend checking the docs to see if there is a more idiomatic way to approach this-- doing so usually comes with added benefits and better cohesion of styles throughout your project.

Comment: But how does the bootstrap variable $font-family-sans-serif override the CSS variable --bs-body-font-family? It seems the css variable is unaffected by changes to the bootstrap variable

Comment: @codeulike— it's possible through the magic of [Sass's `!default` flag](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/variables#default-values), which "assigns a value to a variable `only` if that variable isn’t defined or its value is `null`", which lets you configure/override values before the library uses them to generate CSS. The bootstrap CSS variable _should_ be assigned to your new value. This only works if you configure the order correctly and are importing and compiling the library Sass as part of your project build; if you're not doing that, or trying to do it post-build, it won't work.

Comment: We're talking about two different types of variable, you are talking about SASS variables that start with a $ sign, the OP is talking about a CSS variable `var(--bs-body-font-family) that starts with two dashes -- ... afaik they are unrelated.

Comment: @codeulike - the `bs`-prefixed CSS custom properties (CSS variables) are generated by Bootstrap at build time based on its SASS variable values.  So if you customize/override the SASS variables, when it builds it should generate the CSS variables based upon that customization.